# How do I write string '\t' to a file in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a table generator. However, when I do this in Python

```
create_query += 'ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'\t\'\n'
table.write(create_query)
```

table.write will write to a file

This is what I get.

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
```

I assume that blank space is the actual TAB

However what I want is this.

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

Comment: Can you please give me a reason why this should be downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes for the string as a whole, and escape the backslash:

```
create_query += "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\t'\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
create_query += r"ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'" + "\n"
```